# No Event Logs in Diagnostic on Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, remoting, azure, diagnostics

I'm trying to get .NET Remoting to work on Windows Azure, with a web role. I get a 500 internal server error when trying to access the URL. I've tried using Azure MMC (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuremmc), but I'm only able to get Infrastructure Logs. No Event Logs, Azure Logs or similar. What am I doing wrong?
I've tried setting the log level filter to critical, error, warning and even undefined, without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure, that you want to collect the Event Log information, see http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/05/collecting-event-logs-in-windows-azure.html

It is not automatic since you will get charged for the storage that the event log uses.

On getting remoting to work on Azure have a look at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnisv/archive/2010/05/31/net-remoting-on-windows-azure.aspx

Your problem could be a port issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the connection string in your deployment file ?

In the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file

from

```
<Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

to

```
<Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YOURSTOARGEACCOUNT;AccountKey=YOURACCOUNTKEY" />
```

First you need to create a storage account.